# tSort on jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to sort the results of a jQuery selection with tSort.

HTML:

```
<div sort="2"></div>
<div sort="3"></div>
<div sort="1"></div>
<div sort="4"></div>
<div sort="6"></div>
<div sort="5"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $sort_order = $('div').tsort({attr:'sort'});
</script>
```

I want the result to be: 1,2,3,4,5,6 in the **jQuery object**, not yet inserted into the page.
Is this possible with tSort, or should I write my own algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

It is easier to do it if there is a wrapper of all the `div` elements.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div sort="2">2</div>
<div sort="3">3</div>
<div sort="1">1</div>
<div sort="4">4</div>
<div sort="6">6</div>
<div sort="5">5</div>
</div>
```

Javascript (with jQuery):

```
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.find('div').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +a.getAttribute('sort') - +b.getAttribute('sort');
})
.appendTo($wrapper);
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ckL97/1/).

---

In response to [@Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071790/tim)'s comment, you can place the elements that do not have the `sort` attributes at the back of the `wrapper` element easily, even without jQuery.

Assuming that this is your HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div style="color:red;">red color, without sort attribute</div>
<div style="color:red;" sort="7">red color (sort attribute=7)</div>
<div sort="2">2</div>
<div sort="3">3</div>
<div sort="1">1</div>
<div sort="4">4</div>
<div sort="6">6</div>
<div sort="5">5</div>
</div>
```

You can place the element(s) that do not have the `sort` attribute by having this as your Javascript:

```
// As shown earlier above,
var $wrapper = $('#wrapper');
$wrapper.find('div').sort(function (a, b) {
    return +a.getAttribute('sort') - +b.getAttribute('sort');
})
.appendTo($wrapper);

// New code to add:
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if(divs[i].getAttribute('sort') == null || divs[i].getAttribute('sort') == undefined) {
        divs[i].parentNode.appendChild(divs[i]);   
    }
}
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q92Zg/).

Comment: This works great, is it also possible to put the ones that are 'undefined' behind instead of at the front? (for example: <div>2</div>, without a sort attribute)

Comment: Thanks for your time but this is not yet how I want it to be, in my description I said: *'I want the result to be: 1,2,3,4,5,6 in the jQuery object, not yet inserted into the page'*. With this solution, it's inserted directly into the page.

Comment: @Tim Take a look at my answer, .clone() is the solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

clone it before using .tsort

```
 $sort_order = $('div').clone().tsort({attr:'sort'});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/HdjCT/1/)

Comment: @chris97ong explain...OP said in the question that $sort_order should have the div sorted not the html .tsort() works perfectly fine for sorting the html otherwise...http://jsfiddle.net/HdjCT/2/

Comment: I've tried to implement this.. The sorting works **but** all sort attributes have to be filled in. The ones that don't have a 'sort' attribute will stay where they are.